# how to disable date field using attribute?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to disable my field using attribute .**I don't want to use directive scope property (= ,@ ,&)** I want to use attribute property to disable my **type='date'** field

here is my code

http://plnkr.co/edit/eJDRocLYkr8Krh84vFKY?p=preview

```
 var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.name = 'World';
      $scope.clickb=function(){
        alert('dd')
        $scope.disabletest=true;
      }
    });

    app.directive('test',function(){
      return {
        restrict :'E',
        scope:{},
        template:'<input type="date" ng-disable="disabletest">',
        link:function(s,e,a){

        }

      }
    })
```

I am sending `disable` attribute value in directive to disable field on button click.

I want to disable input field (type='date') on button click using attribute property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This, change `ng-disable` to `ng-disabled`, and create scope variable

```js
var jimApp = angular.module("mainApp",  []);

jimApp.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.disabletest = false;
  $scope.clickb=function(){
    $scope.disabletest=!$scope.disabletest;
  };
});

jimApp.directive('test',function(){
  return {
    restrict :'E',
    template:'<input type="date" ng-disabled="disable">',
    link:function(s,e,a){
      a.$observe('disable', function(value) {
      s.disable = s.$eval(a.disable);
    });
  }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <button ng-click='clickb()'>btn</button>
  <test disable='{{disabletest}}'></test>
</div>
```

Comment: as I said I don't want to use scope property (@,=,&)

Comment: I can only use attr property ..using attr can I disable or watch function

Comment: can I used watch ..? if I want to enable again how i will do .? mean If I have two buttons one for disable and other or enable ?

Comment: it not working can I do like this http://plnkr.co/edit/Qjqeimgs9ZC4SYE7e0wL?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
 ng-disabled="expression"
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body >
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <button ng-click='clickb()'>btn</button>
    <input type="date" ng-disabled='disabletest'>    
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

into directive, you have to specify a property to get disabletest value

Comment: please share plunker..it is not working http://plnkr.co/edit/eJDRocLYkr8Krh84vFKY?p=preview

Comment: can I used watch function ?

Answer (score 0):

Although you really shouldn't use $parent, changing though scope is the best solution what Jimbrooism suggested. Here is the solution without modifying scope. Change to:

```
template:'<input type="date" ng-disabled="$parent.disabletest">',
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZBKv63aroXrao7GO9P2u?p=preview